# Loops though columns to create sums

Tags: vba, loops

Hope you can help me. I have a list of quantities such as this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jelk.png)

I need an autosum of everything that is above in the grey rows.

So far my code:

```
Dim source As Range
Dim iCol As Long
Dim nCol As Long
Dim Cell As Range

Set source = Selection

For iCol = 1 To 5

With source.Columns(iCol)

If Cell.Font.Bold = False Then
i = i + Cell.Value

Else: Cell.Value = i
i = 0


End If

End With
Next iCol
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's what you're after

```
Dim source As Range, col As Range, cell As Range
Dim res As Double

Set source = Selection

With source
    For Each col In .Columns
        For Each cell In col.Cells
            If cell.Font.Bold Then
                cell.Value = res
                res = 0
            Else
                res = res + cell.Value
            End If
        Next cell
    Next col
End With
```

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was after! Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to accept the answer. Thank you!